# Local Storage file load VS MySQL data load speed php

Tags: php, mysql

I am working with long data processing my MySQL take too much CPU load. I am not asking why MySQL take too much CPU load. I want to ask witch one is fastest way to get data.

1) MySQL query 
2) Local storage file (TEXT)

I am loading too many rows in my query's i want batter solution then update my `VPS`

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($my_file)); // Convert local array text file to JSON
```

OR

```
Mysqli_query($con,"select * from data");
```

I will load this query from while loop this is very long loop.

I want to know which method is best to load files much faster and give low load on CPU

and also tell me that is `SSD` boost or normal storage effect on load files from local storage

Comment: Does it really make sense to compare the speed of such different operations? You can't do matching, searching, joining, or other conditions when just loading from a text file.

Comment: The MySQL query should use a `WHERE` clause to filter the data, then it won't load too many rows.

Comment: Yes, ssd will improve time to load file. `file_get_contents()` will attempt to load the entire file content into memory (if your memory is large enough to handle it and correctly setting allowed memory size.). And as I can recall `json_decode()` is not efficient for a very large set.

Comment: Thanks for replay. i am just compare speed. i know mysql have lots of benefits. I am just send same data to all users just want to know which is faster for that. thanks. please tell me is SSD help to improve file load from local storage?

Comment: YES, SSD reads faster than rotating drives.  I hope your LOAD of the file is only ONE time before loop start, then loop it out to all users.